# How to compare two matrices?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, markov-process, matrix

I am working on Markov transition matrices. I would like to find a statistical test to compare them.

The first matrix is considered the population transition matrix and the second one is obtained by estimation from data (counting the transitions).

My first idea was to use a Chi square test on each line of the two matrices. But I have an issue: some of the transitions might be null. When this happens the Chi square test does not work any more.

If someone has an idea, it would be great. In addition, if you have some academic paper on the subject I would like to have the references.

Comment: Hi Paul, welcome to CV. I have corrected some of the spelling. Please check that it still says what you want.

Comment: When you say "some of the transitions might be null" do you mean "have zero probability under the first matrix" or do you mean "have a zero count in the data". The first is easily dealt with by omission of that transition (if you get observations where the first matrix says the probability is zero, you can reject immediately); the second case (a zero count) doesn't of itself invalidate the chi-square.